# i can't detect what wrong have i done in a kinematics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

a question was given to us in assignment which was as follows

> A person moves 20 metres towards north then 30 metres towards east and then moves 30 x 1.414 metres towards south west. The whole trip takes 5 seconds. What is the person's average velocity for this whole journey?

i just squared every magnitude of velocity in all the three directions and then I took square root of that sum

doing so what i got is this number `55.735267112` so this will be the total displacement of that person and dividing this with the given time [5in this case] we get the answer as 11.1 but the answer is 2 m/s

can any one suggest me where is my concept going wrong

Comment: The problem as written isn't very clear. You just gives directions and distance and no time so no velocities can be found.

Comment: but this is the only information given in the question

Comment: @jkeuhlen i think distances and time would be enough for us to calculate the average velocity

Comment: You have distance and then you have a time to stop. That time would be used to find acceleration. You would need time to cover the distance to get a speed.

Comment: @jkeuhlen yes time is given and it is 5secs in this case

Comment: why was this question downvoted

Comment: @agharehanabbas because it is a homework question that is not very interesting or challenging for the people on this site (the downvote is not mine, however).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you draw the path, it looks like this:
[image]

The person moved 10 m in 5 seconds.

Comment: how can you say that he moved 10 metre in 5 seconds as there is no evidence for it

Comment: Look at the vectors. The distance from the endpoint to the starting point is 10 m.

Comment: +1 for the drawing getting the point across better than any calculation

Comment: @LDC3 ok now i can see thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @agharehanabbas The person has a total **displacement** of 10 metres south. Velocity is the displacement per time.